# Comparar data atual com a salva na database e retornar validação

Tags: c#

Estou desenvolvendo um programa onde há um período de teste de 15 dias.

Quando o usuário registra uma conta no aplicativo, o mesmo pega a data da internet e cadastra a data atual e a data do fim do período de teste, que é 15 dias após a data atual, no banco de dados.

```
data_registro | data_vencimento
01/06/2017    | 16/06/2017
```

Como comparo a data fornecida por este código:

```
public static DateTime DataAtual()
{
    var myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.microsoft.com");
    var response = myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    string todaysDates = response.Headers["date"];
    return DateTime.ParseExact(todaysDates,
                               "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'",
                                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat,
                                DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
}
```

O retorno do código acima é feito por este código: `DataAtual().ToShortDateString();` que resulta em: 01/06/2017

Com a do banco de dados, no campo: **`data_vencimento`** para validar se o período de teste acabou ou não?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converte o campo dataLimite para o tipo DateTime

```
   DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dataStringDoBanco); 

   DateTime dataAtual = DataAtual();


    if(dataAtual > dt)
    {
        // O tempo de testes expirou
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

É só comparar uma data com a outra, igual é feito com inteiros.

```
DateTime dataAtual = DataAtual();
DateTime dataLimite = /* Capturar a data do banco */;

if(dataAtual > dataLimite)
{
    // O tempo de testes expirou
}
```

Como o campo no banco é uma *string* (deveria ser `DateTime`, né?) você vai precisar convertê-lo para `DateTime`.

Já que o formato da data será sempre o mesmo, é possível usar o `ParseExact`

```
dataLimite = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Com string isso funciona?

Comment: Não. Nem teria porquê.

Comment: Mas no banco a data está em string

Comment: Então converte pra `DateTime`.